# Using factors when integer reference column already exists

Tags: r, factors

Say I have a dataframe as such, obtained by reading a csv file:

```
    DF1<-data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4),
Names = c('John','Bob','Hannah','Mark'))
```

I want to factorize the names of the second column, as they take a finite amount of values. Nevertheless, an "ID" column already exists, composed of integers which uniquely identify any name in the second.

Is

```
DF1$Names<-factor(DF1$Names)
```

the correct approach, hence "disregarding" the ID column for the matter, or am I missing something?

EDIT: Sorry everyone, I'll try to be more specific: when factorizing a character column, for which every element is ALREADY uniquely identified in another column by integers ("ID"), should I consider the "ID" in any way during the factorization? My doubt comes from the fact that, as I read in the documentation, factorizing something means giving it an integer reference, which in my case already exists.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to be more specific: when factorizing a character column, for which every element is ALREADY uniquely identified in another column by integers ("ID"), should I consider the "ID" in any way during the factorization? My doubt comes from the fact that, as I read in the documentation, factorizing something means giving it an integer reference, which in my case already exists.

Comment: If you want the order of factor levels to be based on the ID, you may need `factor(DF1$Names, levels = unique(DF1$Names))` or order the Names base don the ID

Comment: I understand the concept, but when running your code i get:
[1]<NA><NA><NA><NA>
4 Levels: 1 2 3 4

I don't get why. Thank you

Comment: Is there any use for  id column? Converting a column to a factor does not require the id column in your df!!

Comment: It depends on the end goal. Is there a need to convert the character column to factor in the first place?